# What's the primary differences between CLI and tf.exe command line in TFS?

Tags: tfs

There has been a powerful tf.exe command line tool in TFS. Why do we need this new command line?

1. What's the main function and advantage of it?
2. Since the command line is using VSTS xxx, does this feature also have support for on-premise TFS?
3. Is this similar to Azure CLI?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you working on?

Comment: @Jane Please update your question with proper details as well as add more specific tags

Comment: Working on TFS2017 update3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLI is a new **cross-platform** command line interface, which great for **interactive use or for scripting**. As a developer you can use it for your everyday workflows, like creating pull requests, opening bugs, and more. Bash, PowerShell, etc. users can easily incorporate the VSTS CLI in their scripts.

> Here are a few of the highlights:
>
> - Supports VSTS and TFS (2017 Update 2 and later)
> - Runs on Windows, Linux, and macOS. It is also available as a Docker image, which lets you run VSTS CLI almost anywhere. See the [vsts-cli 
>     Docker repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/vsts-cli/).
> - Integrates with the Git CLI. Once you enable Git alias support via the vsts configure command, you can create a VSTS pull request (and
>     perform other Git related operations) by typing: `git pr create`. If
>     the current directory is a local Git repository connected to VSTS (or 
>     TFS), no other arguments are required. Learn more about [using VSTS
>
>     CLI with Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/git?view=vsts-cli-latest).
> - Natural for Azure CLI users. If you already use the new Azure CLI, you will feel right at home with the VSTS CLI. Both are built on the
>     same platform and are designed to feel natural for users that love
>     command line.
> - Open source on GitHub. We invite you to open issues and suggest new commands. Visit the [vsts-cli repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-cli).

More info to get started, please see the [VSTS CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/vsts/get-started?view=vsts-cli-latest) on learn.microsoft.com.

As for `tf.exe` command, the full name is **Team Foundation version control commands**.  You can use version control commands to do nearly all tasks you can do in Visual Studio, and also several tasks that can’t be done in Visual Studio. You can use the `tf.exe` tool to run version control commands from a command prompt or within a script. However, you couldn't use it for a Git repository and area.